# How to represent nested If-Else blocks in documentation?

Tags: layout, design-patterns, documentation, document-design, decision-making

I want to document a process that has some nested If-Else decision steps. The documentation must be printable, so I don't have a lot of space for proper left indentation to represent the current level and there is a lot of content that cannot be shrunk.

Also, I want to make it clear when an If block ends and you return to the parent scope, or jump the Else block.

Any ideas are welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below where an illustration shows the indentation.

[image: if-else-illustration]

If you want to save space even more, you could fill that structure with ids (1, 1.1, 1.2,...) and reference them below in blocks. This way you wouldn't lose so much horizontal space for the indentation.

[image: blocks with ids]

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I was thinking about adding GoTo and ReturnTo, for example: If it's raining Goto section 1.2.3 | if the rain stopped, ReturnTo 4.5.6